# Query in SSRS for IF condition with 2 results

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to fetch message A when the currency chosen is AUD or CAD and message B if any other currency is chosen, below is what I am trying but not working. Below always display MessageB if I enter AUD, please help:

```
=IIf(First(Fields!FromCurrencyCode.Value ,"CageDBDataset_spRptVoucherCurrencyExchange") ="AUD", "messageA", IIf(First(Fields!FromCurrencyCode.Value ,"CageDBDataset_spRptVoucherCurrencyExchange") = "CAD" ,"messageA","messageB"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking up the value of the first row of the dataset rather than the current row. So if the first row isn't AUD or CAD then you will always get messageB for every row.

Assuming the tablix's dataset is `CageDBDataset_spRptVoucherCurrencyExchange` then the expression you want to use is:

```
=IIf(Fields!FromCurrencyCode.Value = "AUD" OR Fields!FromCurrencyCode.Value  = "CAD", "messageA", "messageB")
```